# How to dynamically generate rows based on value in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, data-warehouse

I'm attempting to write a query to denormalize some data for integrating to our data warehouse, specifically around generating some time slots.

In my source system, I have table that has a start time and and end time and then a column that designates how many appointment slots are available per 15 minute interval.

Example:

```
    Location | Start Time | End Time | Appointment Slots
    A        | 9:00 am    | 5:00 pm  | 2
    B        | 9:00 am    | 5:00 pm  | 1
```

I have already been able to generate a list of 15 minute blocks using a CTE. However, each 15 minute slot just says that 2 slots are available for location A and 1 slot is available for location B. What I'd like is to be able to generate 2 rows per 15 minutes for location A and 1 row per 15 minutes for location B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example of when a "Number" table becomes very handy! If you are not familiar with this concept, read this blog post from Adam Machanic: [You REQUIRE a Numbers Table](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/)

The numbers table is used to join to the Appointment Slots column (in this case) to duplicate each row *AppointmentSlots* number of times.

```
-- A simple recreation of your CTE data...
CREATE  TABLE #AppointmentPeriods
(
    AppointmentLocation CHAR(1),
    AppointmentStartTime TIME,
    AppointmentEndTime TIME,
    AppointmentSlotsAvailable SMALLINT
)

INSERT  INTO #AppointmentPeriods VALUES
    ('A', '09:00', '09:15', 2),
    ('A', '09:15', '09:30', 2),
    ('A', '09:30', '09:45', 2),
    -- ....
    ('A', '16:30', '16:45', 2),
    ('A', '16:45', '17:00', 2),
    ('B', '09:00', '09:15', 1),
    ('B', '09:15', '09:30', 1),
    ('B', '09:30', '09:45', 1),
    -- ....
    ('B', '16:30', '16:45', 1),
    ('B', '16:45', '17:00', 1)


-- Numbers table
CREATE  TABLE #Numbers (NumberValue SMALLINT)

INSERT  INTO #Numbers
-- TOP value should be changed so it is greater than the
-- maximum number of potential appointment slots any location can have
SELECT  TOP 20
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY object_id)
FROM    sys.objects


SELECT  #AppointmentPeriods.*, NumberValue AS AppointmentSlotNumber
FROM    #AppointmentPeriods
        INNER JOIN #Numbers
            ON AppointmentSlotsAvailable >= NumberValue
```

Query output:

```
Location | StartTime | EndTime | AppointmentSlots | SlotNumber
A        | 09:00     | 09:15   | 2                | 1
A        | 09:00     | 09:15   | 2                | 2
A        | 09:15     | 09:30   | 2                | 1
A        | 09:15     | 09:30   | 2                | 2
B        | 16:30     | 16:45   | 1                | 1
B        | 16:45     | 17:00   | 1                | 1
```

PS: There are many ways to generate a numbers table: [SO: What is the best way to create and populate a numbers table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393951/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-and-populate-a-numbers-table)

Comment: Awesome! I knew there would be a handy way to do this. I'll be testing this out tomorrow and will let you know how it works.

Comment: Works like a charm! I actually modified your approach by creating using a CTE to create a numbers table on the fly for the max appointment slots available and used that. Thanks!